# remove commas , and [ ] from a list python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a this funtion

n=5
nums=5 1 4 2 3

```
def LIS(nums, n):
    dp = [] 
    dp_list = [] 

    for i in range(n):
        dp.append(1)
        dp_list.append([nums[i]])
        for j in range(i):
            if nums[j] < nums[i]:
                dp[i] = max(dp[i], dp[j] + 1)
                if len(dp_list[i]) <= len(dp_list[j]):
                    dp_list[i] = dp_list[j] + [nums[i]]
   
    print(dp_list[dp.index(max(dp))])
    return dp_list
```

And I get this result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

But I wan something like this as result

```
1 2 3
```

I have tried using this, but the result still been the same

```
values = ''.join([str(i) for i in LIS(nums,n)])
```

Comment: Have you tried using the space characeter `' '` as a separator?

Comment: values = ' '.join([str(i) for i in LIS(nums,n)]), like this?

Comment: Yes -- does that produce the desired output?

Comment: That's a string representation *of* a list, not a list.

Comment: No, that gave me the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(*dp_list[dp.index(max(dp))])
```